# Regular expression to match an exact number of occurrence for a certain character

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to check if a string has a certain number of occurrence of a character.

Example:

```
$string = '123~456~789~000';
```

I want to verify if this string has exactly 3 instances of the character `~`.

Is that possible using regular expressions?

Comment: can you tag the language please , or do you ask in general?

Comment: @Songo Believe me or not, even version of PHP matters here. In PHP 5.4, I suppose, the easiest way of solving it is just `preg_match_all('#~#', $string)`, as the third param is optional; you can just check the result to know the exact number of `~` characters.

Comment: @raina77ow Thanks for the tip. I re-tagged the question to my specific PHP version 5.3.

Comment: Ah, disregard my comment. ) It makes no sense using regex here, when you can check it with simple substr_count (as you need to count the number of _substrings_, not full-blown _pattern matches_). )

Comment: The qualification of question, "occurrence of **a character**" means that @raina77ow has the best answer, because PHP, like some other languages (including Ruby), has a built-in character-count-in-string function.  This is more efficient than using a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As single character is technically a substring, and the task is to count the number of its occurences, I suppose the most efficient approach lies in using a special PHP function - [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php):

```
$string = '123~456~789~000';
if (substr_count($string, '~') === 3) {
  // string is valid
}
```

Obviously, this approach won't work if you need to count the number of pattern matches (for example, while you can count the number of '0' in your string with `substr_count`, you better use `preg_match_all` to count *digits*).

Yet for this specific question it should be faster overall, as `substr_count` is optimized for one specific goal - count substrings - when `preg_match_all` is more on the universal side. )

Comment: +1 This should be the accepted answer.  I often reply to questions asking for a regex by saying "this sounds like an X-Y problem" but missed doing so here!  Maybe because there was no language tag at the time or the question looked like a theoretical one.  My bad either way!  Just last week I told someone not to use a regex in Ruby and to use `String#count` instead.  You should get the accept here for bringing up the alternative. Thanks.

Comment: +1 and Accepted :) Thanks for providing the right solution to my problem instead of forcing it out using regular expressions (^^,)

Comment: Some of us have no choice but to use regular expressions to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Yes

```
/^[^~]*~[^~]*~[^~]*~[^~]*$/
```

Explanation:

- `^` ... `$` means *the whole string* in many regex dialects
- `[^~]*` a string of zero or more non-tilde characters
- `~` a tilde character

The string can have as many non-tilde characters as necessary, appearing anywhere in the string, but must have exactly three tildes, no more and no less.

Comment: ... or just `/^[^~]*(?:~[^~]*){3}$/`

Comment: In fact, it would be much more easier just to check `.match(/~/).length`, but, as usual, the OP seems to think that mentioning the language used in the regex question is a bad idea. Somehow.

Comment: @raina77ow Evidently my implementation has some problems. Would you mind posting yours as an answer?

Comment: @Asad I would, actually. ) I mentioned the most correct way of solving this problem in my previous comment, but it's meaningless without trying to guess the language used by the OP. Also, somehow I feel this question gonna get updated with some _very important_ details, making half (if not all) the answers incorrect.

Comment: @raina77ow I tagged the question with PHP, sorry for the inconvenience :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe this should work for a variable number of characters:

```
^(?:[^~]*~[^~]*){3}$
```

The advantage here is that you just replace 3 with however many you want to check.

To make it more efficient, it can be written as

```
^[^~]*(?:~[^~]*){3}$
```

Comment: This is suboptimal because it will lead to a mild form of "catastrophic" backtracking in strings that don't have three tildes because many permutations of non-tilde characters have to be checked. As far as I can tell, it's only `O(n^2)`, not `O(2^n)`, but Ray's or raina77ow's solution don't have that problem.

Comment: +1 to @TimPietzcker comment; as a sidenote, how do you expect `?` to matter in `[^~]*?~` expression?

Comment: I started with ., then changed it to [^~] but forgot to take out the laziness

Comment: @Tim I believe this also fixes the backtracking issue, no? I'm not sure, but I don't think there are as many permutations when it's greedy.

Comment: The number or permutations is identical between lazy and greedy. In both cases, your regex needs 400 steps of the regex engine to determined a non-match for `123~123~123~123~123` whereas Ray's needs only 15.

Comment: It is important that I understand this, so I would appreciate if you please bear with me while I try to puzzle this out. I thought the engine will go to the end of the string for the first greedy token, find the end isn't a tilde, then backtrack once, try again, find no tilde, and so on. The number of backtracks will be equal to the length of the string. Where did I go wrong? Thanks for your time. Note: I am talking about strings that have no tildes.

Comment: In short, the 'super-linearity' problem with your regex is that `'---'` part in `'~---~'` can be matched both by prefix and suffix `[^~]*`.

Comment: Ah I see now, ran it through regex coach. So if I remove the first stretch of non tilde's from the bracket '~---~'+many more['---~'] is only checked against the second part of the regex?

Comment: My answer is different from, (and  as I have found, inferior to) raina77ow's solution.

Comment: Well, yes; that'll become `[normal][special normal]{quantifier}` pattern mentioned in [J. Friedl's masterpiece](http://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Mastering_Regular_Expressions.html?id=NYEX-Q9evKoC). )

Comment: What if you wanted to match on there being at least 3, rather than exactly 3?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

**EDIT** based on [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883096/regular-expression-to-match-an-exact-number-of-occurrence-for-a-certain-characte/12883387#comment17444055_12883387) below:

```
<?php

$string = '123~456~789~000';
$total  = preg_match_all('/~/', $string);
echo $total; // Shows 3
```

Comment: As `preg_match_all` returns the number of matches, all that dancing around `$matches` is well redundant.

Comment: Just realized I posted preg_match_all aswer 4 minutes before you so I will keep it. As I said before, it's not my day.

Comment: No, YOU should delete your answer. @raina77ow told me I was overkilling and I fixed it. You instead posted your copy of my answer without that overkill. You are not playing fairly, my friend.